# How can I bridge Wlan to Ethernet through tor?

Tags: security, linux, bridge, torsocks, raspberry-pi

Hi I want to bridge WiFi to Ethernet but I want to do it more anonymous. So how can I do it with the tor network?

By the way I want to use Linux for doing that. So please don't send me Windows Programms. It would be very nice if I could do it with the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

There is [PORTAL of Pi](https://github.com/grugq/PORTALofPi/blob/master/build.sh) which bridges ethernet to wireless on an RPi, intended for use with Arch Linux ARM, there is also [PORTAL of Raspbian](https://github.com/compoterhacker/PORTALofRaspian) which is the same, except ported to the Raspbian.

You should be aware that there are [serious security issues](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/tor-misconception/blob/master/README.md#transparent-proxy-and-tor-router) associated with these kinds of device, especially if the client device is connecting *to* it over wireless, and not ethernet.

Comment: important to note regarding Raspbian is that Raspbian comes preloaded with all kinds of software that can compromise the portal.  Try to scorch it so that only tor is running.  Here's what the author of the original PORTAL of Pi told me https://github.com/grugq/PORTALofPi/pull/27#issuecomment-226162314

Comment: My experience with using ALARM is that it's far less stable (updates randomly break things) than Raspbian, I agree with the authors comments than an attempt to turn Raspbian into a PORTAL would make it far more accessible.